# How do I write a criteria to exclude some entities

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to write a hibernate criteria that excludes certain entities. Here's what I have so far:

```
Criterion exclusion1 = Restrictions.not(Restrictions.conjunction()
    .add(Restrictions.eq("color", "blue");
    .add(Restrictions.eq("type", "aaa"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("subtype1", "bbb"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("subtype2", "ccc"));

Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyObject.class);
crit.add(exclusion1);

List result = crit.list();
```

There are several such exclusion criterion. This seems to do what I want except that if any of the fields are null I want it to be included. e.g an entity with color = blue, type = aaa, subtype1 and subtype2 are null to be included.

How can I rewrite this to **not** exclude that entity?

Comment: An entity with a null subtype1 is not matched by the restriction `eq("subtype1", "bbb")`, so it's also not mapped by the conjunction, so it's included. You don't need to change anything to your code.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. However it's still not doing what I want. I hope someone can figure out  the proper way to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that works the way I want.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948132/429137), it seems that the proper way to do this is to use a subquery to define what should be excluded. e.g.

```
Criterion exclusion1 = Restrictions.conjunction()
    .add(Restrictions.eq("color", "blue"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("type", "aaa"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("subtype1", "bbb"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("subtype2", "ccc"));

Criterion exclusion2 = Restrictions.conjunction()
    .add(Restrictions.eq("color", "blue"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("type", "ddd"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("subtype1", "eee"));

DetachedCriteria excludes = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyObject.class)
    .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
        .add(exclusion1)
        .add(exclusion2))
    .setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyObject.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("state","ok"));
crit.add(Property.forName("id").notIn(excludes));

List results = crit.list();
```

I'm still interested in knowing if there's a better way, but this seems pretty good.